# Chapter headings at different heights

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, chapters

I'm completely new to LaTeX - just started this morning, and I've come up agaisnt an annoying problem.  For some reason when I compile my LaTeX code the vertical position of the Chapter 1 heading is higher than all my subsequent Chapter headings.  Below is a copy of the master file I'm using as well as

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Document  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Title Page  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1in}
{\LARGE Quantifying rates of landscape evolution in carbonate terrains using U-Pb dating of speleothems}
\par
\vspace{1.5in}
{\large Christopher James Martin Smith}
\par
\vfill
A dissertation submitted to the University of Bristol in accordance with the requirements for award of the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in the Faculty of Science.
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
School of Geographical Sciences
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
University of Bristol
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
September 2014
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Preface Numbering  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{roman}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Declaration  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\label{declaration}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\chapter*{Declaration}
\par
I declare that the work in this dissertation was carried out in accordance with the requirements of the University's Regulations and Code of Practice for Research Degree Programmes and that it has not been submitted for any other academic award. Except where indicated by specific reference in the text, the work is the candidate's own work. Work done in collaboration with, or with the assistance of, others, is indicated as such. Any views expressed in the dissertation are those of the author.
\\
\\
\\
\\
\par
SIGNED:
\\
\\
\par
DATE:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Acknowledgements  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\label{acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\par
Text here.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Abstract  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\label{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\par
Text here.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Contents Pages  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\label{listoffigures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\label{listoftables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\newpage
\label{nomeclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\chapter*{Nomenclature}
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Preface Numbering  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Chapter Title %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:intro}


%%%%%%%%%%%
% Spacing %
%%%%%%%%%%%
\doublespacing


%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Sections %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Subsection}
\subsection{Sub-subsection}
\par    


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Chapter Title %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Literature Review}
\label{ch:litrev}


%%%%%%%%%%%
% Spacing %
%%%%%%%%%%%
\doublespacing


%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Sections %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Radioactive Decay}
\subsection{Law of radioactivity}
\par

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{thesis}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the format of the called chapters is exactly the same, so why would Chapter 1 appear to be higher on the page (when compiled and viewed as a pdf) than Chapter 2?

Could it be something to do with the page numbering code that occurs before calling the chapter sections?  Also, I don't know if it's relevant, but I'm using TexMaker to compile my code.

Many thanks,
Chris

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! but.. Actually It's hard to see anything, it would help if you could make your example run without error, removing includes of unsupplied files and preferably (if it still shows the effect) removing the includes alltogether and putting the chapters in the main file.

Comment: Hi David, I've made the edits as you've suggested, but the problem is still occurring (or at least it does in my version of latex).

Comment: Yes I didn't expect that the edits would change the result, just make it easier for people to answer:-) But see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that some of your chapter headings are in the scope of `\doubelspace` and some not. Doublespacing is evil but if you have to, just do it once, at the start.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Document  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Title Page  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1in}
{\LARGE Quantifying rates of landscape evolution in carbonate terrains using U-Pb dating of speleothems\par}%<<<<<<<<<<
\par
\vspace{1.5in}
{\large Christopher James Martin Smith}
\par
\vfill
A dissertation submitted to the University of Bristol in accordance with the requirements for award of the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in the Faculty of Science.
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
School of Geographical Sciences
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
University of Bristol
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
September 2014
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\doublespacing
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Preface Numbering  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{roman}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Declaration  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\label{declaration}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\chapter*{Declaration}
\par
I declare that the work in this dissertation was carried out in accordance with the requirements of the University's Regulations and Code of Practice for Research Degree Programmes and that it has not been submitted for any other academic award. Except where indicated by specific reference in the text, the work is the candidate's own work. Work done in collaboration with, or with the assistance of, others, is indicated as such. Any views expressed in the dissertation are those of the author.
\\
\\
\\
\\
\par
SIGNED:
\\
\\
\par
DATE:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Acknowledgements  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\label{acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\par
Text here.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Abstract  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\label{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\par
Text here.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Contents Pages  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\label{listoffigures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\label{listoftables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\newpage
\label{nomeclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\chapter*{Nomenclature}
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Preface Numbering  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Calling sections  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Chapter Title %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:intro}


%%%%%%%%%%%
% Spacing %
%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Sections %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Subsection}
\subsection{Sub-subsection}
\par

\clearpage

% Chapter Title %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Literature Review}
\label{ch:litrev}


%%%%%%%%%%%
% Spacing %
%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Sections %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Radioactive Decay}
\subsection{Law of radioactivity}
\par

\end{document}
```